# How to define an 'any element' with mandatory attributes

Tags: xsd

I have an XML which can have any element such as:

```
<AnyElements>
  <Any1 id="any1" />
  <Any2 id="any2" />
  ...
</AnyElements>
```

But `id` attribute is mandatory.

How can i define such a xsd?

```
<xs:element name="AnyElements" type="AnyRootType" />
<xs:complexType name="AnyRootType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:any type="AnyChildType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType> 

<xs:complexType name="AnyChildType">
  <xs:attribute ref="id" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on how you're going to define the processing model. Here are some things you need to consider first.

An `any` particle can't be constrained with a type. It comes with an attribute named `processContents` that could be **skip**, **lax**, and the default, **strict**. Once you understand exactly what it means, then going with ***skip*** simply means that you will not be able to enforce your mandatory attribute - the processor will do just that, "skip". If you set it ***lax***, then it will process it **only if** the XSD describing the content is actually available, otherwise it'll skip; The third option ***strict***, requires the XSD describing this extra content to be available - period.

So the `any` particle can be made to work only if the XSD describing the "any" is available during validation. The option I have in mind is kind of limiting, but it has the advantage of being the closest to the "spirit" of an any in that it wouldn't have to derive from a particular base type, or reference some atttributes; for this, a key constraint similar to would approximate your requirement:

```
    <xsd:key name="ofid">
        <xsd:selector xpath="*"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xsd:key>
```

In effect, the key makes the attribute required. The downside may be that each value must be unique, too. Maybe with an attribute named `id` , it is expected;  if instead you wish to apply the pattern to something such as `age`, then it wouldn't work.

If you decide that having XSDs available at runtime is acceptable, then other alternatives may include use of abstract elements or elements with abstract types. The good thing is that it'll bring a more disciplined approach (you'll set the constraints clearly right from the beginning), and without placing uniqueness of values constraints. The downside could be that it creates coupling to another XSD which describes the "contract" - your mandatory attributes.

UPDATE: As per your comment, below is an alternative based on substitution groups. I tried to keep as much as possible your old XSD components names.

**Contract.xsd**: This has the components of your contract. It basically describes the head of your substitution group; it indicates the need for an id attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:complexType name="AnyChildType" abstract="true">
        <xsd:attribute name="id" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="AnyElement" abstract="true" type="AnyChildType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

**GenericInstance.xsd**: It describes the root of your "generic" document. It "integrates" your contract in the context of your defined root element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="Contract.xsd"/>

    <xsd:element name="AnyElements" type="AnyRootType"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="AnyRootType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="AnyElement" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

**SpecificInstance1.xsd**: A particular contract.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="Contract.xsd"/>

    <xsd:element name="SomeElement1" substitutionGroup="AnyElement">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexContent>
                <xsd:extension base="AnyChildType">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>Any content goes.</xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:complexContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

**SpecificInstance2.xsd**: Another contract (shows a different authoring style).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="Contract.xsd"/>

    <xsd:element name="SomeElement2" substitutionGroup="AnyElement" type="SomeElement2Type"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="SomeElement2Type">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="AnyChildType">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Any content goes.</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Visually this is how they're tied together. You can see that the coupling between XSDs is maintained at minimum.

[image]

A sample XML, valid in the scope defined by your generic instance, and the specific ones.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<AnyElements xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SomeElement1 id="1"/>
    <SomeElement2 id="1"/>
</AnyElements>
```

If you're limited to validate your XML using one XSD only, below would be an XSD just for that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="GenericInstance.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="SpecificInstance1.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="SpecificInstance2.xsd"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

I've tested the above with XSD 1.0 running on .NET; having the ability to run on XSD 1.1 or particular features in other XSD processors would invalidate some of what I've said.

Comment: i don't need the values to be unique. how do i go about doing the "alternative" way?

Comment: @humansg I've updated the post with an example based on substitution groups.

Comment: hey.. are you getting my questions correct? I want it to accept any element type. Meaning u can define any tag name as child, but with mandary attribute.. such as `<AnyElementNameHere id="1" />` i tested your codes and it is expecting something with supertype <AnyElement>..

Comment: I believe I do; are you getting my answers correctly? ;)... As I've explained, there are limitations in what XSD 1.0 can do. I suggest you do some background reading on the concepts I've used and then look at my answers again.

Comment: I have run the codes in Java. If I exclude the 2 specific instance xsd (just using generic instance xsd) i will get this error "Invalid content was found starting with element 'SomeElement1'. One of '{AnyElement}' is expected." this shows that the element name cannot be any right?

Comment: I said `If you decide that having XSDs available at runtime is acceptable, then other alternatives may include use of abstract elements`; you asked for alternative, which I provided. You obviously backtracked on that, so then it cannot work...

Comment: So when you mention `having XSDs available at runtime` means to generate XSD (SpecificInstance.xsd) at runtime and then performing validation base on this generated XSD?

Comment: Yes. The idea is that when you design the contract, you don't know about actual implementations ("instance" here) so you're not bound to know all the elements/types: compliance with your requirement is on future implementors. With substitution groups/types you're still limiting `the base type`, but not the element name, so in effect you get an `any element` name there. With constraints you can get away completely from having a contract defined like this. The downside in XSD 1.0 is that it seems to still require XSD available at runtime  and introduces uniqueness.

Comment: You may need to combine your XSD 1.0 with other language like Schematron or RelaxNG. I don't know how all these would work with JAXB. You may want to investigate XSD 1.1, but then this being not that widely supported/adopted you may want to think about interoperability here...